# How to separately assign data to each connected user inside Socket.IO?

Tags: mysql, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to make a card game using Socket.IO, and I am having problems assigning user-specific data (in my case, the cards that each user has).

I'm familiar with JavaScript, but I'm just not sure about whether or not there is a specific feature in Socket.IO for assigning user-specific data, or whether or not I have to store the information in a database / array of sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways to attach data to each socket in socket.io, but it's probably easier to put your data in an associative array, where the keys are the socket id's. Just create the key-value pair upon connection, and make sure you delete the pair on the disconnect event with the delete statement.